# Is there a global config file for Unison synchronization tool?

Tags: configuration, rsync, file-transfer, synchronization, unison

I'd like all my [unison](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/unison-gtk) profiles to have

```
merge = Name * -> meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2
diff = /usr/bin/meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2
confirmmerge = true
```

as options. I know I can add these options to each `.prf` files in `~/.unison/`, but having a global config file for all unison profiles would be preferable. Is there such a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no global config file, but a shortcut:

Use

```
include file
```

to source other config files.

Now you can save the above lines to `common` and add `include common` at the beginning of each of your config files.

There is a more sophisticated setup in the [official manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#powerprofile).