# How do I set up Unison to open the meld GUI when I choose to merge in the Unison GUI

Tags: unison

I am using the Unison GUI in Fedora.

What should I add to my profile to set up "meld" as my merge-tool?

I would like to have a similar user experience as in Git Gui, when I add `meld` as my mergetool.
I would like to see three columns: left local, middle merged document and right server. And after I have chosen what to merge into the middle, I want to press save and close the meld-Gui and afterwards the merged document should overright both the versions local and on the server (this is praobably what 90% of Unison-users want).

How do I set it up this way?
`merge = meld` does not work :(

Can you please also explain the code a bit?
Maybe something similar as [Is there a global config file for Unison synchronization tool?](https://serverfault.com/questions/461940/is-there-a-global-config-file-for-unison-synchronization-tool) would work, but I don't understand the 3 lines of this code:

```
merge = Name * -> meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2
diff = /usr/bin/meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2
confirmmerge = true
```

Comment: This seems like an end-user question, so probably off-topic here. My guess is you'd have the best success asking on the [Unison users](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/lists.html) list, which is monitored by the Unison developers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [documentation for the `merge` option](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#merge). The syntax for `merge` is

```
merge = <PATHSPEC> -> <MERGECMD>
```

Where `<PATHSPEC>` is *which* files you want merged with `<MERGECMD>`. So the line

```
merge = Name * -> meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2
```

is telling Unison to merge all files that match the [path specification](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec) `Name *` (which is all files) and merge them with the command `meld CURRENT1 CURRENT2`. The meaning of `CURRENT1` and `CURRENT2` is explained in [the documentation](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#merge).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can use the Merge mode mentioned on http://meldmerge.org/features.html that I tried to explain in my question, where I get the middle pane? In the Unison-documentation you linked it sounds like I want use "NEW" somewhere? But I don't know the meld syntax well enough to know where to use `NEW`?